# Musical pitch class detection audio library

Tags: algorithm, audio, signal-processing

Does anyone know a good open-source library with detection of harmonic pitch class intensities (chroma) of audio signal? That is, for a given piece of audio, intensity of each of 12 musical pitches.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_pitch_class_profiles

It can be in c, c++, or java as long as the speed (complexity) is good. I don't need it for real-time use, but would use it on hours of material, so speed is a bit more important than quality.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Chromagram plugin](https://code.soundsoftware.ac.uk/projects/qm-vamp-plugins/repository/changes/plugins/ChromagramPlugin.cpp) in the QM [Vamp Plugin](http://vamp-plugins.org/) library. To make sure it's exactly what you want, you can download a binary and test it in [Sonic Visualizer](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org/) before compiling it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look a this webpage. The Website of Dan Ellis has tons of sound-related MATLAB examples

http://www.ee.columbia.edu/~dpwe/resources/matlab/chroma-ansyn/